# How do I broadcast a hostname using Ruby's net-mdns?

Tags: ruby, broadcast, hostname, mdns

I'm new to net-mdns and mDNS in general, so I have just a basic understanding of how the protocol works for now, and I hope the question is pretty self-explanatory.

So far I've seen some examples of how to advertise a *service* with net-mdns, but what I really need is to broadcast a hostname alias, so that my machine can be resolved as "mybox.local" and "othername.local" (it would be nice if "othername.local" were an actual DNS alias, but this is not vital and an A record would do just fine).

I've found [this script](http://www.avahi.org/wiki/Examples/PythonPublishAlias) that basically does what I want, but

- I'm not as fluent in Python as I am in Ruby ;-)
- it depends on avahi and would only run on Linux or BSD, while being portable to other platforms would be a huge plus
- doing it in Ruby would mean plugging it easily in a Rails application, and I happen to be very fluent in Rails. ;-)

I can't seem to find any mention of broadcasting hostnames in the documentation: I've improvised a little, read some of the source code, but with no success so far.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.